# This simple sql query yields empty result

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, wildcard

I am using PhpMysql and this simple query yields an empty result (*"MySQL returned an empty result set"*).

Here is the query: **SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE `prenom` LIKE '%Scott%'**

My table has a row called `prenom`and there is a **'Scott'** value. I have tried with other first names (which I know are in the database) and it does not work either.

The strange thing is that when I use the wildcards between **One letter only**  i.e: SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE `prenom` LIKE '%S%'  it works..

I need help please!

Comment: letter case mismatch perhaps?

Comment: Could you show the first few results of `select * from table2`?

Comment: You have a blank in your statment between `table` and `2` making the 2 the alias for the the table with name `table`. Is `table` the correct name or is it `table2`?

Comment: select * from table 2 works fine and shows all the data. The first two values of the column 'prenom' are 'Tae Ho' and 'Davie'. SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE `prenom` LIKE '%Davie%' does not work either.

Comment: @ bish: I use Phpmyadmin query box and it recognizes correctly my table `Table 2`.

Comment: if you change `LIKE '%Scott%'` to `= 'Scott'`, do you get what you would expect from that?

Comment: What is the collation for the `prenom` column? Any change if instead your query is ``SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE `prenom` = '%Scott%'`` ? What about ``SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE `prenom` LIKE '%Scott%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`` ?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 => This does not work either.

Comment: Hi Isaac, it did not work either ; The collation is currently itf8_bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the pb was that due to the collation type instead of SCOTT, the file was encoded with spaces S C O T T. I had to reformat the file in utf8 to fix this!